# Handle gather timeout in voice api twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm using [gather](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) tag from Twilio API. You can specify `timeout` as a number of seconds Twilio will wait for first digit/word. The problem is that timeout causes hanging up the call. Is there any chance to receive request in case of timeout? It would be really cool to say sth like `Hello, can you repeat?` instead of hanging up call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can after your gather message have a say messsage (not nested), in theory you can do it as much as yu want, and then add more gathers